# How to fill black borders of VM without VMWare tools. VMWare player 17 free

Tags: windows-10, drivers, resolution, vmware-player, fullscreen

Hello I've been trying to setup my VM so that it fills in the black borders that surround it. I can get it to do this by installing the VMWare tools, but the problem is that when I do this it breaks some of my games that I hope to run on it. From my testing it's the SVGA Driver that's breaking it and it's also the driver that's responsible for filling in the borders.

So far what I've tried checking specify monitor settings and changing max resolution to the desired size, then unchecking DPI scaling(didn't work). I then tried adding this to VMWare preferences pref.autoFitFullScreen = "stretchGuestToHost", pref.autoFitGuestToWindow = "FALSE". Which was better but only helped in full screen mode and wasn't exactly what I was looking for.

Does anyone know how to emulate the screen filling effect of SVGA Driver or just a way to manually set the resolution to what I want?

Answer (score 1):

> How to fill black borders of VM without VMWare tools. ..... I can get
> it to do this by installing the VMWare tools, but the problem is that
> when I do this it breaks some of my games that I hope to run on it.

You cannot.

VMware Tools is what allows variable resolution. So you must install VMware Tools to fill the black space.

If you truly must go without tools to install non-compliant games, then you are stuck with the resolution you get.

VMware Workstation V17 here with Tools installed and all is well.

FWIW I have had VMware from V1 to v17 inclusive and needing Tools has always been de rigeur.

Comment: So there's not even a way to manually set the VM's screen resolution to one of my choosing?

Comment: No, unfortunately not.  You may have some success altering the size of the main VMware window (so not full screen).

Comment: That is a shame. They really should implement a way to change the resolution manually. Thanks for your help.